# Can we route from a component in ember js?

Tags: ember.js

I have a component which has a button with an action like
            **{{action 'create'}}**
and inside the action create i wrote like  **this.transitionTo('page.new');**
But i am getting an exception like **Cannot read property 'enter' of undefined** can anyone answer please?Just want to know is that possible to route from a component?

Comment: Could you show code responsible for component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the answer it is possible.we can use simply use the following code from our components action

`App.Router.router.transitionTo('new route');`

and we will get a call back for this,in which we can set the new route's model.Use the following code for that.

```
App.Router.router.transitionTo('your route here').then(function(newRoute){

    newRoute.currentModel.set('property','value');

});
```

Answer (score 7):

The way to do that is to use `this.sendAction()` from your component and bubble it up to the router. The router can then call `this.transitionTo()`.

The way `link-to` does it is by injecting routing `_routing: inject.service('-routing'),`

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.1.0/packages/ember-routing-views/lib/components/link-to.js#L530

Answer (score 4):

`Ember.Component` is extended from `Ember.View` and you cant use `this.transitionTo` in a view. It can be done only through a controller/router.

If you want a transition inside the component on clicking, you could use the `link-to` helper, but if you still want to be able to handle that action, read: http://emberjs.com/guides/components/handling-user-interaction-with-actions/ and the guide after it.

Answer (score 0):

Injection is the last thing you wanna do. The way you communicate actions between routes and components is to use the sendAction Method [Send Action](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/)

**template.hbs**

```
{{your-component  action="nameOfYourRouteAction" }}
```

**route.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({


ratesService: Ember.inject.service(),
  model() {
    //return yourdata
  },


  actions: {
    nameOfYourRouteAction(...args){
        this.transitionTo(...args);
    }
  }
});
```

**in your component.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    actions: {
        toggleTransition: function(...args) {
            this.sendAction('action', ...args);
        }
    }
});
```

**component.hbs**

```
<button {{action "toggleTransition" 'your route'}}>Change Route</button>
```

Comment: Bit of a pain in the ass that you get the #link-to helper for free in the component template but you can't replicate that behaviour in the component js without faffing about passing messages up which is always a hassle. Especially if you are several component layers down.

Comment: well I guess its better than doing anti pattern route injections ;)